# product of two gamma random variables

Tags: self-study, random-variable, gamma-distribution

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, and generated from $\Gamma(\alpha,1)$ and $\Gamma(\alpha+ \frac{1}{2},1)$, 
and $Y$ is 
$$Y=3 \sqrt{X_1X_2}$$
Is 
$$\mathbb{E}Y = 3 \sqrt{\alpha^2+ \alpha\frac{1}{2} }?$$

Steps:
$$\mathbb{E}Y = 3 \sqrt{\mathbb{E}X_1\mathbb{E}X_2}$$
$$\mathbb{E}\Gamma= \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$$ so
$$\mathbb{E}Y = 3 \sqrt{(\alpha)(\alpha+\frac{1}{2})}$$
$$\mathbb{E}Y = 3 \sqrt{(\alpha)(\alpha+\frac{1}{2})}$$
$$\mathbb{E}Y = 3 \sqrt{\alpha^2+ \alpha\frac{1}{2} }$$

Comment: Please fix your formula so we know what you want

Comment: Please add the self-study tag to homework problems and show us what you've done, in this case your attempted derivation.  We don't just answer homework problems for people but rather try to help them overcome whatever has their own ability to solve them blocked.

Comment: Re your title. You are not multiplying the distributions, you are multiplying two random variables (or rather, computing three times their geometric mean), and then asking about the mean of that.

Comment: @user2723494 I am pretty sure that you *cannot* do $E[\sqrt{X_1}]=\sqrt{E[X_1]}$

Comment: Since $x\to\sqrt{x}$ is a concave function, $\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{X}]\le\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X]}$ by Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_1^{1/2}X_2^{1/2}] &= \mathbb{E}[X_1^{1/2}]\mathbb{E}[X_2^{1/2}]\\
&= \int_0^\infty x^{1/2} \frac{x^{\alpha-1}\exp\{-x\}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\text{d}x\,\int_0^\infty x^{1/2} \frac{x^{\alpha-1/2}\exp\{-x\}}{\Gamma(\alpha+ 1/2)}\text{d}x\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha-1/2}\exp\{-x\}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\text{d}x\,\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha}\exp\{-x\}}{\Gamma(\alpha+1/2)}\text{d}x\\&= \dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha+1/2)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\,\dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha+1/2)}\\
&= \dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\\ &=\alpha
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you derive the second line? According to wikipedia the square root of a gamma distribution is a Nakagami distribution and the mean you wrote is not the same as the one on wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you. Where did the second line come from?

Comment: To derive the second line you don't need to actually know the distribution of the square root of a gamma r.v., you can just use the law of the unconscious statistician, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician.

Comment: Would Var Y be the second derivative?